# How Linux can compare old and new password?

Tags: security, password, pam, hashsum, shadow

I know that on Linux (at least debian) every password are hashed and stored in `/etc/shadow`.

However thanks to the `libpam-cracklib` you can add some rules on passwords. For instance in `/etc/pam.d/common-password` you can set `Difok` which is a parameter that indicate the number of letter that can be the same between an old and a new password.

But how linux can know when I type in an new password the similarity with my old pasword as it doesn't know my real password (it just have a hash)?

Thanks !

Comment: **Probably** tries all passwords that are just a few letters away from the new one. If it does not find a match, then the new one is different enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you ask a PAM module to change a password (or participate in changing a password), the module can retrieve both the new password and the old, as given by the user: as [Christopher](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/29678/christopher) points out, `passwd` asks for the old password as well as the new (unless you’re running it as `root` and changing another user’s password). The module can use that information to compare both passwords, without having to somehow reverse the current hash or enumerate variants.

The PAM functions involved include [`pam_sm_chauthtok`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pam_sm_chauthtok.3.html) and [`pam_get_item`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pam_get_item.3.html), whose documentation (and the other pages referenced there) should help you understand what’s going on. You can see how it’s done in `libpam-cracklib`’s [source code](https://github.com/linux-pam/linux-pam/blob/master/modules/pam_cracklib/pam_cracklib.c#L726).